# htaccess to rewrite all files to index.php

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I need to rewrite all urls, even .js, .css, images and etc to index.php

I've tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

But it doesn't seem to work for css and images

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work" - You should describe exactly what happens - what response to you get from the server for these resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
> ```

Having 2 conditions, one that checks whether the request maps to a file and the other that checks that it doesn't is rather pointless. However, this is likely to generate a rewrite loop. You need to ensure you don't rewrite the rewritten request to `index.php`. In other words, exclude `index.php` from the rewrite.

For example, if you want to rewrite *everything* then you just need a single directive:

```
RewriteRule !index\.php$ index.php [L]
```

This states that for every request that is *not* (`!` prefix) for `index.php` rewrite it to `index.php`.

No need for the capturing subpattern (ie. `(.*)` in your original *pattern*), since this does not appear to be used by your script. (?) No need for the `QSA` flag either since the query string is appended to the *susbstitution* by default (although I expect you'll be parsing the query string from the initial request anyway in your script).